# confusion of char *notes[] = {"Ab", "F#", "B", "Gb", "D"}; and char**

Tags: c++, pointers

I am really confused this type of pointer definition:

```
char *notes[] = {"Ab", "F#", "B", "Gb", "D"};`.
```

I understand that `notes` here is an array of pointer to char, which I understand as notes' elements should all be the addresses of char typed variables. Where am I wrong? So how does this work?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *notes[] = {"Ab", "F#", "B", "Gb", "D"};
    cout << *(char**)(notes+2);
}
```

Also what is the `char**` cast there and what is its significance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In this sense, `char *notes[]` means `notes[]` is an array pointer to char

It means that `nodes` is an array of `char*`, i.e. an array of character pointers.

> `notes[]` 's elements should all be the addresses of char typed variables.

C implicitly converts *string literals* (i.e. character sequences enclosed in double quotes) to null-terminated C strings, and produces addresses of the initial character as pointers for adding to the array. That is how the array gets initialized.

Here is an example of how the data could be placed in memory:

```
Address Value Character
------- ----- ---------
1000000    65 A
1000001    98 b
1000002    00 NULL terminator
1000003    70 F
1000004    35 #
1000005    00 NULL terminator
1000006    66 B
1000007    00 NULL terminator
1000008    71 G
1000009    98 b
1000010    00 NULL terminator
1000011    68 D
1000012    00 NULL terminator
```

Then your array of pointers will be initialized as follows:

```
notes = {1000000, 1000003, 1000006, 1000008, 1000011};
```

**Note:** Above layout is only an example. String literals may not necessarily be placed in memory back-to-back.

Answer (score 4):

Your statement:

> `char *nodes[]` means `nodes[]` is an array pointer to `char`

isn't exactly true. `char *nodes[]` means that `nodes` is an array of character pointers, and in your case, it is full of string literals.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *notes[]
```

This is an array of char pointers.

```
char **notes
```

would be a pointer to a char pointer, kind of like a two dimensional array of characters, working similarly to `char *notes[]`, **however**, this will not allocate stack space, while the array will.

The way this works is that a **string** like "Ab" or "F#" are really a sequence of chars, which is why char *note = "Ab" is perfectly valid, because the pointer, `note`, points to the first char of the sequence that makes up the string.

So `char *notes[]` is an array or arrays of sorts, which makes it similar to `char **notes`, because this is a pointer that points to the beginning of a sequence *of pointers* which each point to the beginning of a sequence of chars.

Comment: The main difference here is that `char *notes[] = { ... }` is going to allocate stack space for the array, while a `char **` will not -- it's the size of any other pointer. (Clarifying for readers that while the two types are *similar*, they are not the same in this context.)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand that `*` has a different semnificance depending on context:

- in a *type declaration* it means **pointer type**.
  e.g.: `int *p` - `p` is a pointer to `int`
- else it is the **dereference operator**:
  e.g.: `*p = 6` - the value found at the address *held* by `p` becomes `6`

Regarding your structure:

```
char *notes[] = {"Ab", "F#", "B", "Gb", "D"}
```

`notes` is an array of 5 (deduced from initializer) elements of type `char *` (pointer to char)

`"asdf"` is a string literal. A string literal has type `char []` (C) / `const char []` (C++). (array of [constant] chars), which can decay to pointers: can, in some context, be cast to `char *` (unfortunately allowing the drop of `const`, but that is another can of worms)